# What does 見ぬ/minu mean in this sentence?

Tags: negation, classical-japanese, auxiliary-ず

The phrase is: `mada minu kimi e tsudzuku`. I believe the kana is: `まだ見ぬきみへつづく`。

Comment: Using kanji, it is まだ見ぬ君へ続く.

Comment: possible duplicate of [About negative form {-ず} and {-ぬ}](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/235/about-negative-form-%e3%81%9a-and-%e3%81%ac)

Comment: @Flaw I disagree. Only because I didn't even know what the word was to begin with. Much less it was a literary form of the negative form of a verb.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hrGOB2WMJB8&t=1m13s

Comment: @sawa-san, いい曲~~(でも槙原敬之?)

Comment: @Chocolate さん、世代がバレてしまったでしょうか。

Comment: @sawa-san, いいえ、まだナゾの中です^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

見ぬ is the archaic/literary form of 見ない, the negative form of the verb 見る, to see/meet. So I think the whole sentence literally translates to "(Something: "the road" or something I guess) leads to you, whom I've not seen yet"

Comment: All the [lyrics](http://www.lyricstime.com/romeo-x-juliet-inori-you-raise-me-up-lyrics.html) if that helps.

Comment: わ！かたかな！www OK I'll read this page ^^ http://www.kasi-time.com/item-9825.html

Comment: Adding the keyword 歌詞 is a good way to find lyrics in [Japanese](http://www.kasi-time.com/item-9825.html).

Comment: @dotnetN00b so...the subject for the 続く is 凍える嵐の夜(a freezing stormy night), right?

Comment: @Chocolate [It doesn't seem like it](http://www.animelyrics.com/anime/romeoxjuliet/inoriyouraise.htm)

Comment: @dotnetN00b Ah, so it's more like 凍える嵐の夜にも(even in a freezing stormy night). But now I'm not sure about the subject for 続く...

Comment: Man, lyrics are tough still amongst the toughest for me. If someone could drop a translation of that verse in chat, that would be great

Comment: @Louis I've already posted the english lyrics. See "it doesn't seem like it" link above.

Comment: @dotnetN00b I see. 教えて海渡る風 was confusing for me. But those lyrics might be too liberal, "I continue on" makes no reference to 君へ. Edit: nevermind, I guess it does.

Comment: I think song lyrics are often so profound and abstract, and hard to fully understand...

Answer (score 1):

In most cases 'minu' translates to 'unseen'.

The full sentence まだ見ぬ君へ続く can be roughly translated to "(It) still continues unseen to you"

Comment: The まだ modifies the verb 見ぬ, not 続く. So it's not "still" but "(not) yet"

Comment: You're right. Don't know how I missed that :P