# What does the ぬ in 詰まぬ mean?

Tags: conjugations, classical-japanese, auxiliary-ず

I encountered a Shogi saying:

> 三桂あって詰まぬこと無し

And I'm pretty confused about the ぬ there. If it was る I'd expect the meaning to be something like:
"If you have 3 knights, you can't be mated"

But looking at it's explanation [here](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q135769478) and [here](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B0%86%E6%A3%8B%E3%81%AE%E6%A0%BC%E8%A8%80#.E3.81.95) it looks like they are talking about mating (attacking) and not getting mated (defending).

Well, while typing this I suddenly realized I can just search google for ぬ instead of る, so I'll guess I'll be answering my own question as I was encouraged to do on other StackExchange sites.

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/235/difference-between-negative-forms-%E3%81%9A-and-%E3%81%AC/5886#5886

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ぬ is a classical form of ない. While it's not often used you will probably still encounter it in some situations (proverbs are a great example).

In this situtation 詰まぬ=詰まない meaning "not being mated" so a translation for the proverb may be:

> With 3 knights, there's always a mate (no such thing as being unmatable?)

Comment: What's so interesting is that あって is very un-classical...