# Meaning of "[気張]{きば}らずゆっくりやっていこうね"

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

> **気張らず**ゆっくりやっていこうね

'ゆっくりやっていこう’ means "I'll keep on going slowly", right?
But what is 気張らず?

Comment: Did you look up 気張る?

Comment: If it's the ～ず grammar which is confusing you: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/235/difference-between-negative-forms-%E3%81%9A-and-%E3%81%AC

Answer (score 3):

「気張らず」 ＝ 「気張らずに」 ＝ 「気張らないで」

Those are the negative and continuative forms of 「気張る」 = "exert or strain oneself".

Thus, 「気張らず」 means "without straining oneself", "taking it easy", etc.

> "Let's take it easy and go slowly, shall we?"