# What does “本気になれぬ” mean?

Tags: translation, song-lyrics, archaic-language

So I am going through song lyrics, and the new grammar and vocab that I learn from them goes into my studying. One song I came across was “Wolf Boy” (ウルフボーイ) by Morning Musume (モーニング娘).

The first line of the song is:

> 本気に**なれぬ**ウルフボーイ

and is translated to be:

> "You don't show the real you, wolf boy"

Is this translation correct? Because I don't know what なれぬ means, and I don't understand how this translates. Someone please explain it to me. Maybe it's slang that I am not getting.

Comment: -ぬ is an archaic form of the negative (like -ない). So, なれぬ means なれない (i.e. the negative of the potential of なる). See also: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/235/3437

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a literal translation, it's wrong.

> 本気になれぬ
>   ≒本気になれない
>   ≒(You) can't get serious.

(Side note: if you look at the rest of the lyrics, it's pretty clear that at least some of the clauses before 「ウルフボーイ」 don't act as relative clauses, so I don't think the meaning of this line is "The wolf boy who can't get serious", but just "You can't get serious; wolf boy.")

But, most song translations are not literal, and rightly so, so expect to find a lot more things like this if you're trying to learn from them.

Comment: This is killing my eyes.  Besides, the question is about なれぬ, not ならぬ.

Comment: Oh wow, I misread it entirely, whoops. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I tried fixing the answer (and the font).

Comment: After looking into the lyrics, I think it _is_ a relative clause. There are many factors hinder having such young girls (actually most of the 共通語 speakers today) use ぬ in 終止形, while It's not unnatural to parallel relative and non-relative clauses in lyrics, for at least it doesn't differ in word order.