# 思うようにならず - what does it mean?

Tags: grammar

A definition of 辛気臭い【しんきくさい】 (三省堂）：

> 思うようにならず、いらいらするさま。また、気がめいるさま

Nara often implies something happening naturally, zu stands for 'without', so does the whole compound adverb stand for 'subconsciously'? 'without thinking'?

Answer (score 9):

> Nara often implies something happening naturally, zu stands for 'without', so does the whole compound adverb stand for 'subconsciously'? 'without thinking'?

No. First of all, Nara is 動詞{どうし}, a verb. But you are correct in that this indicates "something happening naturally", since we call this なる, 無意識動詞{むいしきどうし}, literally *a verb without consciousness*.

Second, zu **does not** denote "without", but, to quote [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20190302111452/http://www.geocities.jp/nm3032nakatsu/koten/kt04.html) source:

> **ず    ①～ない （打ち消し）** ( around the middle of the linked page )

but denotes **denial** (which is an auxiliary). In this phrase, it denies the above verb "naru/なる”.

#### Grammar Breakdown

思うようにならない。
＝思う(連体形{れんたいけい}), in English *to think* + よう（様）に an auxiliary, 連用形{れんようけい}, in English *as I expect*  + なら the verb, 連用形, in English (*to become*) + ない。the auxiliary, 終止形{しゅうしけい}, in English, *denying the former verb/auxiliary/adjective verb, etc*.

So the whole meaning is "**Not having gone as I had expected**".

Answer (score 2):

This means something like 思うようにならない、（そして）いらいらする様子。
ならず is a different form of the negation. You can get more detailed information here:
[What is the difference between the negative forms -ず and -ぬ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/235/what-is-the-difference-between-the-negative-forms-%E3%81%9A-and-%E3%81%AC)

Answer (score 2):

A wild grammatical construction appears!

思うようにならず, ~~ is the same as saying 思うようにならないで, ~~

行かず = 行かないで

ご飯を食べず, 寝ました (Went to bed without eating dinner)

---

If something was 思うようになる then it would be "conceivable"

so 思うようにならないで, ~ is something like "inconceivably" or "does not even lend to imagining" perhaps.