# Meaning of “かぶらず” and usage of に

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, verbs

I came across a sentence which had かぶらず. As, per the picture, the meaning is nothing to wear on head. However, I was trying to figure out whether かぶらず is part of conjugation of the verb かぶる, however, many websites were not showing such conjugation, and the meaning of word かぶらず for that matter. Thereafter, I googled it and found it meant not wearing.

So

> my question is; whether is かぶらず is the conjugation of かぶる or is it
>   something else?
>
> Is it some sort of a negative form to be used with particle も which also has the function of showing nothingness?

Secondly, I just wanted to seek clarification on usage of particle に, are we using this particle and not が, because if we use that particle it would me, my head has nothing to wear, which can also be misunderstood as, my head, literally has nothing to wear, which would be different from there is nothing to put on my head, which the author is trying to show.

Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: The verb かぶる also wouldn't be used for "wear" with 靴 anyway. You use はく for wearing shoes (and other things on the lower half of your body).

Comment: Also as a note to @APK, generally if you have follow up questions like that, you should create a new question.

Comment: @APK, If you have a new question, please create a new question post. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> かぶる - base form
>
> かぶら - negative/irrealis/mizen form
>
> かぶらず - add the negation ず.

ず is a way of negating a verb that is more old fashioned/formal/archaic. It's still used quite often though. Here is a link to an answer about ず: [What is the difference between the negative forms -ず and -ぬ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/235/what-is-the-difference-between-the-negative-forms-%E3%81%9A-and-%E3%81%AC)

As for the に, I suppose the simple answer is that 被る{かぶる} is a transitive (他動詞) verb and the に indicates the indirect object. The direct object would be something like a hat, which you could put on. But then, there is the question of where you put the hat. The answer is: on your head.

> 頭に帽子を被る = (I) put a hat on my head.
>
> 頭に被る = on my head

Comment: Can we consider ず as the old way if it's still used on a fairly regular basis today?

Comment: Good point. I updated my answer.

Comment: Well, I was interested in that phrasing because it was unsure of whether or not it derived from an archaic form or not.  Do you know if it was?

Comment: Do you mean if ない derives from ず? I think there are some theories that it might have (via ぬ): https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84#Etymology_3