# Negative verb form vs Verb + ない stem + ぬ

Tags: grammar, verbs

What's the difference?

For example: 気付かない vs 気付かぬ

Comment: I'm wondering if you meant to put ぬ in the title? You have め. ぬ seems to be just an archaism that was used in same was as  ない. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/235/what-is-the-difference-between-the-negative-forms-%E3%81%9A-and-%E3%81%AC

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant to use ぬ.

Thanks the link answers my question.