# Why do many adverbs end with ず?

Tags: etymology, adverbs

A quick search on [jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/*%E3%81%9A) reveals that many of the first page results of words that end with a ず are adverbs. So this type of adverb is common.

In fact, it's true (at least for these first page results) that a word is an adverb if and only if the final ず is written in kana instead of being part of the reading of a kanji.

This doesn't seem like a coincidence.

I know that ず was historically a negative conjugation (per [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/235)), but I can't really why that would make it a common adverb ending.

Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Comment: Including the adverb tag in the jisho search might make it easier to navigate. And there are some adverbs where the final mora is ず but it can be written in kanji (しずしず, 静々, 静静)

Comment: Oooh handy.

I'll leave the linked search as is because I think it's noteworthy that there are so many first-page adverb results (7), compared to 1 for *つ and 0 for *か (just a couple random examples).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so many adverbs with ず in Japanese adverbs but I find some examples of Japanese adverbs with "ず" at the end of a word are;

Group A: ず means negative conjugation
あいかわらず (as not changed)
あしからず (do not treat it as bad thing)
おもいがけず (as not supposed)
おもわず (as not supposed)

Group B: ず is a part of Mimetic word
うずうず (itchy)
ぐずぐず (tardily)

Adverbs are changed shape of verb.
Above Group A is changed with negative form of verbs.